# Determine if a string of characters are unique using quicksort

Tags: c++, algorithm, quick-sort

This will determine if a string is unique or not using quicksort, so that it should take \$O(nlogn)\$ time and not \$O(n^2)\$ time.

I will call the `test` function code from `main`.

This runs successfully, but when I try to write a randomized partition, it will fail. I have written that code separately.

**FindUniqueCharInString.h**

```
#define MAX 15
class FindUniqueCharInString
{
public:
    FindUniqueCharInString(void);
    ~FindUniqueCharInString(void);
    void test();

private:
    void swap(int index1, int index2);
    void quickSort(int start, int end);
    int partition(int start, int end);

    char arr[15];
};
```

**FindUniqueCharInString.cpp**

```
#include "FindUniqueCharInString.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

FindUniqueCharInString::FindUniqueCharInString(void)
{
    char *tempArr = "SOMESTRING";

    strcpy(arr,tempArr);
}

FindUniqueCharInString::~FindUniqueCharInString(void)
{
}

void FindUniqueCharInString::test()
{
    quickSort(0,strlen(arr));

    for(int i = 0;i<strlen(arr);i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i] << " ";
    }

    cout<<endl;

    bool isUnique = true;
    for(int i = 0;i<strlen(arr) - 1;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == arr[i+1])
            isUnique = false;
    }

    if(isUnique)
        cout<<"Unique" <<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Not unique"<<endl;

}

void FindUniqueCharInString::swap(int index1, int index2)
{
    if(arr[index1] != arr[index2])
    {
        char temp = arr[index1];
        arr[index1] = arr[index2];
        arr[index2] = temp;
    }
}

void FindUniqueCharInString::quickSort(int start, int end)
{
    if(start >= end)
        return;

    int p = partition(start,end);
    quickSort(start, p - 1);
    quickSort(p + 1,end);
}

int FindUniqueCharInString::partition(int start, int end)
{
    int pivot = arr[end - 1];
    int t = start;

    for(int i = start; i< end-1; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] <= pivot)
        {
            swap(i,t);
            t++;
        }
    }

    swap(t,end - 1); //swap index and pivot pos

    return t;
}
```

**Randomize partition function:**

```
int FindUniqueCharInString::partition(int start, int end)
{
    int m = start + (end - start)/2;
    int pivot = arr[m];
    int t = start;

    swap(m,end -1); //putting pivot element to end

    for(int i = start; i< end-1; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] <= pivot)
        {
            swap(i,t);
            t++;
        }
    }

    swap(t,end - 1); //swap index and pivot pos

    return t;
}
```

Comment: Can you include a failing test case? I tried to comment but could not since I joined only recently.

Comment: @user2371765 same example I have taken in running program is failing for randomized partition.

Comment: Aren't questions about code with errors off-topic? @Jamal?

Comment: @Zeta: Yes, but I didn't close this one right away.  I was hesitant since some code was written separately.  Feel free to flag-to-close if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the problem with partitioning (unfortunately, the "working" code works by accident). You correctly setup the algorithm for `end` be a one-off index. It means that for the left subarray `p` is its end. However you call it with `p - 1`, and a valid last character doesn't participate in partitioning. Fix is simple:

```
    quickSort(start, p);
```

- `#define MAX 15`. I don't see any use of `MAX`
- `FindUniqueCharInString` suggests that the class is there to *find* unique characters. Turns out that it doesn't *find* anything, but instead it tests for character uniqueness. You need to rename it to reflect its purpose (hint: if you can't find a good name, most likely a class has no purpose, and a free function will do the same just fine).
- An utility method like `test()` shouldn't print anything, but return its results. In this case, it should return a `bool`, for example

  ```
  for(int i = 0;i<strlen(arr) - 1;i++)
  {
      if(arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
          return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
  ```
- Always use curly braces, even for one-liners.
- Of course the code will fail badly if the input string is longer than 15 characters. Consider using `std::vector` instead of hardcoded array.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It solved my problem. Thought I do not understand problem with `p-1`, shouldn't I skip pivot element because it is already at sorted position. Please look at thumbnail of video I am following for quicksort (http://tinyurl.com/j92wsmb), it uses p-1 and p+1 to skip pivot. May be I have made some other terrible mistake, but just to clarify.

Comment: @PranitKothari `p` _does_ skip pivot! `p-1` (unwantedly) skips one extra element. `p-1` works if the `end` parameter denotes _last valid_ element. In your setup it denotes _first invalid_ one.

Answer (score 7):

#### Complexity

If the intent was to meet an \$O(N log N)\$ requirement, you've technically failed--quicksort has an *expected* complexity proportional to N log N, but big-O deals strictly with the worst-case complexity--and worst-case complexity of quicksort is \$O(N^2)\$.

#### Class Design

One of the old basic ideas of how to do object-oriented design is to start by writing down a one-page (or less) description of what the program is supposed to do. You then pick out the nouns that form the major themes in that description. Those are your classes.

The point of that is to note that most classes should normally represent *nouns*<sup>1</sup>. Things that exist. Objects. In a *typical* case they should not represent verbs.

In this case, however, you have one primary class--and its name is a verb, not a noun. This leads to a lot of question over whether it makes sense for this class to be a class, or whether we have kind of a conglomeration of "stuff" thrown together into something that says it's a class, but isn't doesn't form a particularly coherent...thing.

#### Standard Containers

Good uses for C style arrays in C++ are quite rare. Your `arr` doesn't strike me as one of them. If you really need a fixed-size array, you should probably use `std::array` instead. Otherwise, you're probably best off using `std::vector`.

#### Standard Algorithms

The standard library already has algorithms to handle the job at hand. Most code should just use `st::sort` followed by `std::unique`, rather than attempting to craft the same on your own.

#### Self-defeating design

Right now, you've limited the collection size to only 15 elements. For such a small size, a simpler sorting algorithm (e.g., insertion sort) will almost always be at least a little faster than a quicksort. In short, combining the elements you have in the way you have just doesn't make sense.

#### Use of strlen

If you insist on using `strlen` at all, you shouldn't call it in the condition of a `for` loop, like:

```
for (int i=0; i<strlen(foo); i++)
```

A *few* compilers know how to optimize this by hoisting the call to `strlen` out of the loop, but most don't. With those compilers, this loop will have \$O(N^2)\$ complexity instead of the `O(N)` you probably want/expect.

Note that if you used `std::vector` or `std::string` for your storage, this wouldn't be a problem. Unlike `strlen`, both these guarantee that you can find the size with \$O(1)\$ complexity instead of \$O(N)\$.

#### Side Effect-ridden code

Most of your functions implicitly modify `FindUniqueCharInString::arr`. It's generally much better to avoid this when possible--and it's pretty trivial in most of these cases. Just for a trivial example, right now your `swap` is passed to integers, `i` and `j`, and it swaps `arr[i]` with `arr[j]`. It would be much better to pass (for example) pointers or references to the contents, so the modifications are explicit:

```
swap(i, j); // ambiguous, implicit side effects on `arr`

swap(arr[i], arr[j]); // clear, effect on `arr` is obvious.
```

#### Summary

At least in my opinion, the other issues pale compared to just making good use of the standard library.

```
std::string arr {"SOMESTRING"};
std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
auto end = std::unique(arr.begin(), arr.end());

// show the unique characters    
std::copy(arr.begin(), end, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

---

<sup>1. The primary exception to this is function objects--i.e., classes that act mostly like a function, including overloading `operator()` to do whatever it is they do</sup>